# normalizer of two p-Sylow intersection

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $N(P_1 \cap P_2)$ be the intersection of 2 p-Sylow, $P_1$ and $P_2$. I have 2 questions (which I put in a single question here because connected, and I tried to prove the last one).

First of all, given a group, is the intersection between p-Sylows always the same? (isomorphically) So if for instance I find two 2-Sylows of cardinality 8 whose intersection is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$, do I have that every intersection of every 2-Sylow is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$? I had thought that if the action on the set of p-Sylow is double transitive then it's trivial, but is there some weaker criterion?

Then I was wondering if given the example above it is always true that $P_1<N(P_1 \cap P_2)$, because my teacher once used this fact, but I am not sure if it is a general property or it worked only in the specific case. I have thought that since the conjugate of $P_1$ by the action of $P_1$ is itself, then the elements of $P_1 \cap P_2$ are bound to go on $P_1$, and so $P_2$ is bound to go on a $P_k$ whose intersection with $P_1$ is again $P_1 \cap P_2$. Would this be enough to prove that we always have $P_1<N(P_1 \cap P_2)$?

Comment: The $2$-Sylow subgroups of the symmetric group $S_4$ embedded in $S_5$ are also $2$-Sylow subgroups of the $S_5$. Now take two different embeddings of the $S_4$ (one fixing $5$, the other $4$). Their intersection is $S_3$ (fixing $4$ and $5$) having $2$-Sylow subgroups generated by a $2$-cycle. Now choose in both $S_4$'s a $2$-Sylow subgroup containing let's say the $2$-cycle $(1 2)$. Do you see why none of the $2$-Sylow subgroups normalizes (=centralizes, as we speak about $Z_2$) this intersection?

Comment: So, if I have understood, you take the intersection of two different $D_4$ embedded in $S_5$ and if you take one fixing $5$ and the other $4$, then the intersection is a 2-group in $S_3$ which has to be a transposition, $(12)$ for instance. Then if you act coniugating, you can send (can you really do this? not so sure aboout that) one of the two groups in a way that now the intersection isn't $(12)$ but the other one in $D_4$. So (if it exists a coniugation that does this) it is not true that the intersection of the two 2-Sylows contains $D_4$. But where's the error in the reasoning above?

Comment: Some elements of $D_4$ will map $(1 2)$ to different $2$-cycle, let's say $(3 4)$, so the intersection with $P_k$ won't be $(1 2)$ but $(3 4)$.

Comment: Yeah indeed, I don't know what I was thinking, also the reasoning at the bottom of my question is wrong. The coniugate of $P_1 \cap P_2$ by $P_1$ is in $P_1$, but you can't say it is exactly $P_1  \cap  P_2$, it could be something isomorphic (as you showed using the transpositions in $D_4$).

Answer (score 3):

It is **not** in general true that the every two Sylow subgroups are contained in the normalizer of their intersection. It is however true when these two subgroups are *abelian*. Indeed, use the fact that every two Sylow subgroups of a group are conjugate with each other and the commutativity of the subgroups(it is really straightforward). So, I guess that in the exercise your professor assigned you the subgroups were small and their commutativity should be apparent. Otherwise, it is a mistake to infer that.

Answer (score 2):

The intersection of Sylow $p$-subgroups does not have to be the same.  Let $F = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, and let $G = \textrm{GL}_3(F)$, the group of $3$ by $3$ matrices with entries in $F$ whose determinant is nonzero.  The order of $G$ is $$p^3(p-1)(p^2-1)(p^3-1)$$

which shows you that the subgroup

$$P = \{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & b \\ 0 & 1 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} : a, b ,c \in F\}$$

of order $p^3$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.  Let

$$w_0 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$w = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Then let

$$P_1 := w_0Pw_0^{-1} = \{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ a & 1 & 0 \\ b & c & 1 \end{pmatrix} \}$$

$$P_2 = wPw^{-1} = \{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & c \\ a & 1 & b \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\}$$

So we have three Sylow $p$-subgroups $P, P_1 , P_2$, with $P \cap P_1$ trivial, but $P \cap P_2$ has order $p^2$.  I'm not sure about your question with the normalizer, I'll have to think about it more.